# Unable to use angular cli in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, angular

It says I have used the pro version so I need the licence or free trial.How can I get the free version of angular cli on eclipse.I have tried to reinstall it but did not work.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Eclipse does not support Angular CLI. Try taking a look at IntelliJ's trial version. (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an IDE to use Angular CLI. All you need is a Terminal.
Run the following steps:

1. You need Nodejs. If you don't have it yet, just go this [official
   nodejs page](https://nodejs.org/en/) & download the recommended version then install it.
2. `$ npm install -g @angular/cli`

Answer (score 0):

**[Angular Eclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angular-eclipse) is open source** and integrates angular-cli with [Terminal](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/ngTerminal), [Wizards](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/ngWizards) and [Launches](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/ngLaunches).